# Listview on click event not working

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

i am trying to add on click listener in a listview but when clicked, no action. can you help me find what i did wrong?
This is adapted from one of the example in android tutorial

```
public class Main extends Activity {
private ListView menuListView;
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
        //getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main,menu);

        //Get the Menu List from resources
        menu = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menu);
        //get the drawer Layout
        menuDrawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        ArrayAdapter<String> itemAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.custom_menu_list,menu);
        //get the list view
        menuListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        menuListView.setAdapter(itemAdapter);
        menuListView.setOnItemClickListener(new menuItemClickListener());
}
private class menuItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener{

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Log.d("Check","clicked");
        }
    }
}//
}
```

This is the xml of the listview textview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="6dip"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    />
```

This is the main xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF">
    <!-- The main content view -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"/>
    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <ListView android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#000000"/>


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/toastMsg"
        android:text="Hello"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: are you getting in exceptions in logs? add main.xml code too

Comment: I have code similar to your code and it works fine, the only difference I call setAdapter after calling setOnItemClickListener.  I do not know why or if that would make any difference, but give it a shot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify you're main.xml file, remove the TextView and run the code. It works

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF">
    <!-- The main content view -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"/>
    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <ListView android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```